# SVN partial copy between repositories with history

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm trying to partially copy one repository to another.

In the source repo I've created a new user account (USERNAME) and denied access to all the directories I'd like to omit in the destination repo. Under that account name I've tried to do a svnsync, but it still copies all directories from the source, including the directories with no access.

```
svnsync synchronize https://destinationURL https://sourceURL --source-username USERNAME --source-password PASSWORD
```

I was hoping by using the username with limited access to the source repo that only the accessible directories would be synced to the destination repo.

Is there some setting or flag I'm missing to prevent everything from being copied?

**[EDIT]** - This repo is large so an svndump is impractical. Essentially I'm trying to pull it apart to make smaller, more manageable repos, but with their complete histories intact.

Answer (score 0):

`svnsync` synchronize **changesets** in repos, **not trees**.

You can to think about svnrdump (which, contrary to svndump, allow to dump only part of repository)